# Blocking database driver & async web framework

Tags: python, async-await, sqlalchemy, blocking, aiohttp

Async web frameworks are here though ORMs often aren't async-friendly. Though is there any reason to care about this in the typical scenario where your database is hosted in the same local network as your server for the average service? The waiting time on Network I/O to the database will be negligible compared to external networks requests after all.

In my specific case, I have a Python aiohttp web server which I want to connect to a PostgreSQL db. I would like a lot to use SQL Alchemy as ORM layer though this implies blocking requests since there is no support for async database drivers in SQL Alchemy ORM layer (there are alternatives such as GINO or async-peewee though they aren't solid for production use in my case). This question applies to any async web server that may be willing to make blocking requests though.

This isn't really discussed anywhere. The debate is whether you'll be willing to give up using a stable but synchronous ORM in order to use an async web server or not. Is there any harm I'm overseeing here considering that the database will be in the same network as the server?

One can spawn threads to make these blocking requests though this a thing more to manage in your application if you're using an ORM which may implicitly emit SQL queries against the database based on attributes or methods access.

Answer (score 1):

Just use [databases](https://pypi.org/project/databases/) - it supports *async* drivers and SQL Alchemy. You  can extract `query` from Alchemy ORM and execute it async.

But if you have legacy code around it - wrap it

```
def runsql(session):
    return session.query(...).filter(...).all()

result = await loop.run_in_executor(
        None, functools.partial(runsql, session))
```

Comment: It is a really good option and I'll consider it, thanks! One thing though: it does not support SQL Alchemy as ORM, it supports SQL Alchemy Core for query building.